Getting the game Maplestory to run in steam under bottles
I have successfully gotten steam to launch under bottles utilizing sys-wine-9.0. Downloading the game works just fine and launching the game by pressing play seems to work just fine.
Now the issue that I have, the game in question is Maplestory. The game launches and it's own launcher launches just fine, but... bottles triggers the wine debugger and then... the game fails to proceed.
Is there a way to get past this wine debug unscathed?

Maplestory has a "borked" rating in proton db. Don't think wine is going to work for this one. https://www.protondb.com/app/216150 They describe the same behavior as you do.
